# border-spacing for inside borders only

Tags: html, css, sass

I want my table cells to have a margin between them within same row, so I tried setting `border-spacing: smth`, but it also forces the left-most and right-most to have that same margin from table's outside border. Is it possible to avoid such scenario and apply spacing only between cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the first and last `td` and reset their margins to 0.

```
td {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
td:first-of-type, td:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: `margin` does not work for smth with `display: table-cell` as far as I'm concerned, correct me if I'm wrong. So I don't mean exactly to use `margin` attribute, just space between cells to be precise

Comment: I thought maybe padding would work too, but you said margin in your question. Glad it helped :)